# how to call this Js func from code behind vb,net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a popup `JavaScript` function in my `asp.net` page and I want to call the function from code behind vb.net

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pop(div) {
            document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'block';
        }
        function hide(div) {
            document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
        }
        //To detect escape button
        document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
            evt = evt || window.event;
            if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
                hide('popDiv');
            }
        };

        function GoBack() {
            window.history.forward();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). This is not a free code-writing service nor tutorial site. You're expected to have already done basic research, to present the code you've tried with a description of how it's not working and what the expected result would be. As it stands, your question is "too broad".

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to run a js function from the VB code behind - the VB is running on the server to create the page.  The js is running within the browser once the page has been downloaded.

Comment: i need it because i want the popup div to show after i inserting the records 
to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `RegisterStartupScript` in code-behind, your Javascript function will be executed once the page is loaded in the browser:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "JSScript", string.Format("pop('{0}');", divID))
```

However, it may be simpler to make the `div` accessible in code-behind:

```
<div id="div1" runat="server" ... >
```

and set the `display` attribute there:

```
div1.Style("display") = "block"
```

or

```
div1.Style.Remove("display")
```

Comment: u was right 
i used div accessibility in code-behind with  if (condition)